# Moodle external db plugin

Tags: database, plugins, external, moodle

I use Moodle 2.7 external db enrollment plugin. However, the plugin  does not create or assign any student and there is no error produced. When I run the sync script or try to log in as student or teacher, no courses are created and users are not assigned to their courses
I tried Moodle forum and documents but could not find the answer.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

the fields of external DB contains non English letters, when the fields changed to only English letters, it worked!